Ubuntu 24.04 'Recovery Menu' font too small to read
Need to use the Recovery Menu to run FSCK to the system. Umount
But the font is so small I can't read it (no even with a magnifier).
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo P50.
I changed the Grub Menu font to suit, but the Recovery Menu still too small.
Any ideas ?

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-menu-font-size    Does this link help?

No, That links only updates the GRUB menu and not the "recovery menu" I have changed the font type and size of the GRUB menu many times with no effect to the Recovery Options Menu.

Very unusual. I ran recovery on my machine. No problems with fonts.  Options:  1/ Myself, I would install a Linux distro on a usb stick for a live boot. Then, open terminal, and run fsck on the target drive.  2/ Force fsck to run at boot for the root drive. Commands:  (a) sudo touch /forcefsck  .  Then after the fsck completes, remove the forcefsk... (b) sudo rm /forcefsk
